# Are there red light districts in St. Petersburg or Moscow?

Tags: safety, russia, moscow, saint-petersburg, sex

We are going to travel to Russia (St Petersburg and Moscow). Is there any red light district (or something like that) in these cities? Where are these places?

Are they safe for tourists?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_by_country this is a very useful page.

Comment: Are you asking because you want to see Russia's version of a red light district, or because you want to know if they're dangerous in case you end up walking through one by accident? Or both?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No**, there are no such districts in either Moscow or St. Petersburg as of 2016. Prostitution is [illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Russia) in Russia and locations which become *too well-known* to the public are frequently raided and shut-down.

Obviously prostitution still exists, but it's not centered in any particular street or district. There are many websites online dedicated to reviews of such establishments, so you can try your luck on the Internet.

As for safety: unless you speak Russian without an accent, **I wouldn't risk it**. While those two cities can be generally safe, putting yourself in contact with the underground sex trade is a risky endeavor for foreigners.

Comment: @ReZa unless you speak Russian without an accent, I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: +1 to everybody. This can be **very** unsafe for you.

Comment: I'mma bounty this asap.

Comment: @ReZa, I cannot agree more with VMAtm and others. It is not safe particularly for foreigners and it is not safe at all, even for locals. Total crap shot. If you have opportunity, find a local who have attended such places before or use word of mouth.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Outrageous suggestion. Implies one will actually have to acknowledge a female as being a human being. Unrealistic IMO.

Comment: @Fiksdal: Insanity!

Comment: It seems you're assuming OP wants to go to Russia's Reeperbahn. And maybe they do. But it's safe to assume others will come to this question and this answer via Google. So for both the OP and anyone else we should probably also answer so as to address people looking for advice to make sure they don't happen upon such places accidentally. Well maybe (-: